# How to convert Untiy Configuration from 1.2.* to 2.0.*

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config, unity-container

In Unity 1.2, I had this text in web.config

> ```
>       <type type="IRouteRegistry" mapTo="TownHall.Mvc.Routing.TownHallRoutes,TownHall.Mvc">
>         <typeConfig extensionType="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.TypeInjectionElement,Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration">
>           <constructor>
>             <param name="routes" parameterType="RouteCollection">
>               <dependency name="ApplicationRouteCollection" />
>             </param>
>             <param name="routeHandlerType" parameterType="System.Type">
>               <dependency name="RegisterRoutesHandler"/>
>             </param>
>             <param name="settings" parameterType="IAppSettings">
>               <dependency/>
>             </param>
>           </constructor>
>         </typeConfig>
>       </type>
> ```

I convert to bellow text in Unity 2.0.*

> ```
>  <register type="IRouteRegistry" mapTo="TownHall.Mvc.Routing.TownHallRoutes, TownHall.Mvc">
>    <constructor>
>      <param name="routes" type="RouteCollection">
>        <dependency name="ApplicationRouteCollection" />
>      </param>
>      <param name="routeHandlerType" type="System.Type">
>        <dependency name="RegisterRoutesHandler" />
>      </param>
>      <param name="settings" type="IAppSettings">
>        <dependency />
>      </param>
>    </constructor>
>  </register>
> ```

But it got error

> The type name or alias RouteCollection could not be resolved. Please check your >configuration file and verify this type name.

at

> ```
>        IUnityContainer townhallContainer = new UnityContainer();
>        UnityConfigurationSection config = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
>
>        config.Configure(townhallContainer); // I got error here
>
>        return townhallContainer;
> ```

How do I convert them to Unity 2.0 configuration file ???

Sorry my bad English

Comment: Start with learning to spell correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone,
I've just resolved this problem.
The Problem came from **type="RouteCollection"** and I need delete that text